# creating choropleth map of Arizona with counties and an excel file of data about the counties

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap, jqvmap

I am fairly new to data visualization using javascript and its various libraries and plugins. I am trying to create an interactive state map of Arizone with all its counties, I have  data pertaining to schools within these counties that I would be exploring or presenting through the map. 
Right now I am just going in circles as to which plugin or tool I should be using I have checked out Polymaps, jqvmaps, jvectorMaps.  It would be great help if someone who has done something similar could throw in suggestions.

Also if some one can shed some light on using the google maps api, and what would be the learning curve to getting started. 
Thanks

Comment: There is no objective answer to either of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I intend to do something similar for all the counties in US and so I have collected some information that might be of use to you. Here's the overall approach.

1. Collect the data like list of counties each with it's FIPS id, display name and svg map. This information is in [public domain](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Blank_Map_of_Arizona.svg). Like the blank SVG map of Arizona shown below.

[image: svg map of arizona]

2. Store all this data by county id in a database like MySQL or whatever you fancy. Add the data pertaining to schools. Now you can export the subset of data to a csv file for Analysis. I prefer using R. Once you have your map and data ready, proceed to the next step.
3. You can overlay this data on the map using Raphael as shown in [this article](http://jebruner.com/2011/11/how-to-build-an-interactive-map-with-open-source-tools/)

or

Use this open source JQuery [plugin](http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/) and customize it to create your own clickable heatmap.

Let me know how you progress and we can bounce some ideas.

EDIT: Here's another [nice article](http://flowingdata.com/2009/11/12/how-to-make-a-us-county-thematic-map-using-free-tools/#more-3581) how to make a Choropleth using free tools. This look slike the best approach to make what you are going after. It uses Python so it should be neat and clean.